# PHPExcel How to set a date in cell

Tags: date, cell, phpexcel, xls

I need to put a date in a cell, when I take a look to its format it looks like *14/03/01.

The value I put is a simple string and for that reason when I get the calculated values ignores the date I entered because it compares in a calendar (well, a column with all the dates of the actual year) the date that I entered with the dates to set a proper value corresponding the date entered.

Is there a way to put the format that Excel expects?

Answer (score 7):

MS Excel uses a timestamp value for dates, and then masks it for display purposes; not a formatted string.

From `02types.php` in the `/Examples` folder:

```
$dateTimeNow = time();    //  Get a Unix/PHP timestamp value for the date/time
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()           // Convert Unix timestamp to a MS Excel 
    ->setCellValue('A9', 'Date/Time')    //  serialized timestamp, and set that as 
    ->setCellValue('B9', 'Date')         //  the cell value
    ->setCellValue(
        'C9', 
        PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( $dateTimeNow )
    );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()        // Format as date and time
    ->getStyle('C9')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
```

The `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` method will take a Unix timestamp or a string (formatted like those you might pass to `strtotime()`) and convert it to a MS Excel timestamp value; while the `setFormatCode()` calls are setting that cell to a format mask to indicate to MS Excel that the cell contains a value that should be displayed as a date and/or time

Comment: The process I'm doing right now is this: `$date = $start_date->getTimestamp();  $mainSheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);  $mainSheet->setCellValue('B1', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($date));  $mainSheet->getStyle('B1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);` But still not working.

Comment: Please explain "Not Working". What is the value of `$start_date->getTimestamp();`? What is actually being stored in cell B1? It should be a float (a value of 41720.00 is today's date with the default 1900 calendar).... a simple `getValue()` on that cell after setting it should tell you.

Comment: Yes, it is a float `41720.618009259`

Comment: So the value is being set correctly; and a `getFormattedValue()` call should return a string of "2014-03-22" (with the format mask set to FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2). If you save using the Excel2007 or Excel5 Writer, what do you see in MS EXcel when you open the file?

Comment: I generated the excel using Excel5 and in that cell I get that `22/03/2014  15:25:27`the problem is the time, is there a way to not include the time?

Comment: You shouldn't see any time at all in MS Excel if you're using a date-only mask like `PHPExcel_Style_Numb‌​erFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY`: that should mask the display to only show the date, formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. Look at the number mask in MS Excel and see what it shows

Comment: Btw, the function `getFormattedValue()` shows only 22/03/14 as expected but when I save the Excel it shows date and time.

Comment: That should normally only happen if you're storing a string value in the cell rather than a date; clearly you've found a critical bug in the code that somehow escaped all my tests... If the number format mask isn't being saved correctly, then I'll need to find some way to replicate it and then release a fix

Comment: `getFormattedValue()` shouldn't show "22/03/14" for that mask, it should show "2014-03-22"

Comment: Well, I set the format mask as FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY. In that case is correct, no?

Comment: Yes, `FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY` is a mask of `dd/mm/yy`, which should display `22/03/14`.... so at least that means the error is only in the Writer, not in the setting the mask itself, or in getFormattedValue()... that narrows it down a bit for me

Comment: Well, but save the file is a minor problem. I have to set the date correctly to retrieve the right value in PHP. Is this bug affecting in this case too?

Comment: Clearly not... you're setting the date, applying a mask to the cell, and are able to get the value with the format mask applied using getFormattedValue

Comment: So, for some reason when I get the value calculated through formulas it ignores the date because if you test in the Excel with no date, you retrieve the values that I get in PHP.

Comment: I'm beginning to lose you here, I hadn't realised you were using any formulas.... but date calculation formulas should still work correctly; all MS Excel date functions are implemented in PHPExcel

Comment: Is there a way to format to 22/03/2014? I'm just trying random things and see if it works because I'm stuck here.

Comment: You're not limited to the predefined formats; you can use almost any format mask that you can use in Excel itself; so `dd/mm/yyyy` will give you `22/03/2014`

Comment: Well, I find a solution. I converted all dates in numbers, then with PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel() I get the number for the date but for some reason with the numbers after the dot it does not work so, I deleted these numbers and with only 41720 in that case works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

```
$duree = '08:00:00';
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder() );
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($row, $num, $duree);
$sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($row, $num)
      ->getNumberFormat()
      ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);
```

And in my cell i can see 08:00