# Custom date format in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, strtotime

In my excel file I am building from PHP the first row is the header one. I need to put there several dates as column header. Each date is (in dd/mm/yyyy format) 15/mm/yyyy starting from 15/01/2007 and ending with 15/12/2018 stepping month by month.
My code is this:

```
for($anno = $annoMin; $anno<=$annoMax; $anno++){
    for($mese = 1; $mese <= 12; $mese++){
        $mese = sprintf("%02s", $mese);
        $periodo = '15/'.$mese.'/'.$anno;
        $periodo = strtotime($periodo);
        $periodo = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($periodo);
        array_push($header_array,$periodo);
    }
}
```

I build the date as a string, convert it into a unix timestap, convert it into an excel date and push it into the $header_array.
Then I draw the cells in the excel:

```
$ews->fromArray($header_array, ' ', 'A1');
```

Finally I format the cells where there is a date as:

```
$ews->getStyle('U1:EJ1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
```

ISSUES ARE:

1. Actually my code is returning 'False' for each cell with a date;
2. I need to add a custom mask that is not listed in the PHPExcel library: MM/YYYY to be shown in each cell.

For the first issue: I have checked different SO questions and followed [mainly this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575173/phpexcel-how-to-set-a-date-in-cell). with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
$periodo = '15/'.$mese.'/'.$anno;
$periodo = strtotime($periodo);
```

which would give a string values of `15/1/2015`, `15/2/2015`... ``15/12/2015`that you're then attempting to convert to a unix timestamp using`strtotime()`.

If you read the [PHP Docs on date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) used by the `strtotime()` function, you'll see that a `/` separator tells PHP that the date string is US date format.... i.e. mm/dd/yyyy`giving a month value of`15` in every case, and (of course) there is no month 15

Either use a dash (`-`) rather than a `/` to indicate European (`dd-mm-yyyy`) rather than US date format

```
$periodo = '15-'.$mese.'-'.$anno;
$periodo = strtotime($periodo);
```

or re-order the values to use US format

```
$periodo = $mese.'/'.'15/'.$anno;
$periodo = strtotime($periodo);
```

---

And for the second part of your question.... you can supply almost any format mask that MS Excel recognises, you're not restricted to the built-in formats; so:

```
$ews->getStyle('U1:EJ1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('mm/yyyy');
```

The format code is simply a string value

Comment: Sidenote: can I get rid of the time in the cell? The value I see in the formula bar is like this: '14/01/2008  23:00:00' and I'd like to see only '14/01/2008'?

Comment: Ensure that you're using GMT/UTC.... by setting timezone; or you might choose to use `gmmktime()` and `gmdate()` instead of `strtotime()`; or switch to using PHP's DateTime objects with a UTC DateTimeZone instead