# Yii2, ExportMenu: How to format a date, that Excel recognise it automatically as date?

Tags: excel, yii2

I use in my grids the extension [yii2-export](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-export) to export data to XLS and XLSX. Whatever I try, Excel does not automatically recognize the dates. I have tried e.g. the following columns formats:

```
'mydate',  // yyyy-mm-dd
'mydate:date',   // dd.mm.yyyy
[
    'attribute' => 'mydate',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return date("m/d/Y",  strtotime($model->mydate));
    },
],   // mm/dd/yyyy
```

I suppose, I have to mark the dates as date. But how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

In grid configuration add:

```
'onRenderDataCell' => function ($cell, $content, $model, $key, $index, $grid) {
    if ($key == 'mydate') {
        $cell->setValue(\PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(\Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp($model->$key)));
    }
},
```

Absolutely **not** 100% sure if it works. Some namespaces fixing might be needed as well. The idea is to change the content of the cell, I was checking possible options from PHPExcel repo but I have not verified this.

Few links from it has been taken:

- [Export menu docs #40](http://demos.krajee.com/export)
- [PHPExcel_Shared_Date class](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php)
- [PHPExcel example file with different types](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/02types-xls.php)

Comment: Thanks. It looks very promising.

Comment: 1. problem: $key does not return the name of the attribute, but ID of the row.

Comment: 2. problem: $cell->setValue(\PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(\Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp('2016-01-01')) returns: '42370.394699074' and is not as date in Excel interpreted.

Comment: I tried also asDate() and asDatetime(), but without any success.

Comment: Ad.2. I guess adding format is a must as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22575893/3364821  
Ad.1. Bummer. You need to locale proper attribute, try dumping $cell, maybe there is something.

Comment: Ad.2. $cell is the PHPExcel work sheet object instance "PHPExcel_Cell", which have the method "setDataType". This method has the following constants: 
TYPE_BOOL,
TYPE_ERROR,
TYPE_FORMULA,
TYPE_INLINE,
TYPE_NULL,
TYPE_NUMERIC,
TYPE_STRING.
But no TYPE_DATE...

Comment: Ad.2. $cell->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2) is not possilble. (There is no such method in PHPExcel_Cell).

Comment: Ad.2. What I can do is: $cell->setDataType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC), but it does not help.

Comment: Does it work with $cell->setValue('42370') ? In the linked answer's comment someone removed the part after dot.

Comment: $cell->setValue('42370'); returns 42370. (As number).

Answer (score 0):

In your model you should provide the date like following:

```
public function getDate(){
   return \PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp($this->date));

}
```

Your excel export contains the normal columns and a formatting function for the specific column.

```
<?= ExportMenu::widget([
        'onRenderSheet' => function($sheet, $grid){
               $sheet->getStyle('What ever column it is(A, B, C, ..)')->getNumberFormat()
                     ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
               }
         },

         'columns' => [                      
               [
                   'attribute' => 'date',
                   'label' => 'Datum',
               ],


        ]);?>`
```